# Json_encode response to int array

Tags: php, android, json

Good day,

I'm new to `PHP` and `JSON`,

I have a response that looks like this:

```
{"products":[{"price":"52.00"},{"price":"11.00"},{"price":"123.00"},{"price":"12.00"},{"price":"1.00"},{"price":"145.00"},{"price":"123.00"}],"success":1}
```

Now, I must display the Total Pice in my android application in a `textView (totalTextView)`
Can anybody please assist me with this.

It is a crucial part of my application due Friday 28Nov'14 
Please will be much appreciated.

**My php code:**

```
<?php

/*
* Following code will list all the prices
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["price"] = $row["price"];

    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON


error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: get the json data in android side and convert it to integer and add get the sum :)

Comment: Do you know how to get data from php server to android? or you need help for only to set the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSONObject`. it also accepts a `String` parameter when you instantiate it.

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using gson ;) ... I think, it's the best way and very easy :)

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is an ugly JSON response, if you are not planning to add any columns to products array. In other words, if they're all "price" keep them as price array, products is not needed. Whatever I think parsing response to the int array will be something like this (did not test it though):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseString); //In case the response isn't JSONObject.
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("products");
int[] priceArray = new priceArray[jsonArray.length()];

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
    JsonObject element = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    priceArray[i] = element.getInt("price");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use these lines in your script as below:

```
$response = array();
$product["products"] = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $product["products"][]["price"] = $row["price"];

}

$response = array_merge($response, $product);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["price"] = $row["price"];
    $total_price += $row["price"];
    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;
$response['total_price']=$total_price;
```